# solving $y' - yy'x^2-x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can i solve this?

$$y' - yy'x^2-x=0$$

I only got to the homogeneous solution wich I found is (I just divided by $y'$)

$$y=\frac{1}{x^2}$$

But I don't know how to get the particular solution, I have for certain that it's not a constant as I tried to find it in every way possibile, could anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: $y=\frac 1{x^2}$ seems to cause $x=0$ in the original...  Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$y'-yy'x^{ 2 }-x=0\\ { y }^{ \prime  }\left( 1-y{ x }^{ 2 } \right) -x=0\\ \frac { dy }{ dx } \left( 1-y{ x }^{ 2 } \right) -x=0\\ 1-y{ x }^{ 2 }-x{ x }^{ \prime  }=0\\ z={ x }^{ 2 }\Rightarrow { z }^{ \prime  }=2x{ x }^{ \prime  }$$ $$1-yz-\frac { { z }^{ \prime  } }{ 2 } =0$$ 
which  becomes to the "Ordinary differential equation 
" respect to the  $z$

> $$2-2yz-{ z }^{ \prime  }=0$$

$$2-2yz-{ z }^{ \prime  }=0\\ { z }^{ \prime  }=-2yz\\ \frac { { z }^{ \prime  } }{ z } =-2y\\ \int { \frac { dz }{ z } =-2\int { ydy }  } \\ \ln { \left| z \right|  } =-{ y }^{ 2 }+C\\ z=C{ e }^{ -{ y }^{ 2 } }\\ z=C(y){ e }^{ -{ y }^{ 2 } }\\ { z }^{ \prime  }={ C }^{ \prime  }{ (y)e }^{ -{ y }^{ 2 } }-2y{ e }^{ -{ y }^{ 2 } }C(y)\\ 2-2yC(y){ e }^{ -{ y }^{ 2 } }-{ C }^{ \prime  }{ (y)e }^{ -{ y }^{ 2 } }+2y{ e }^{ -{ y }^{ 2 } }C(y)=0\\ { C }^{ \prime  }{ (y)e }^{ -{ y }^{ 2 } }=2\\ { C }^{ \prime  }(y)=2e^{ { y }^{ 2 } }\\ C(y)=2\int { { e }^{ { y }^{ 2 } } } dy+C\\ z={ e }^{ -{ y }^{ 2 } }\left( 2\int { { e }^{ { y }^{ 2 } } } dy+C \right) $$
so the final answer is :

> $$\\ { x }^{ 2 }={ e }^{ -{ y }^{ 2 } }\left( 2\int { { e }^{ { y }^{ 2 } } } dy+C \right) $$

Comment: Where did the dy go and isn't x'=1?

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife,$dy\left( 1-y{ x }^{ 2 } \right) -xdx=0\\ \left( 1-y{ x }^{ 2 } \right) -x\frac { dx }{ dy } =0\\ 1-y{ x }^{ 2 }-x{ x }^{ \prime  }=0$

Comment: So you just multiply with $dx$ everywhere? What about the product rule for differentiation.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i don't know how to resolve the final differential, i've come to $$\frac{z'}{z} = -2y$$ but now? i don't know how to integrate the -2y because i don't know the function! also how do i treat each variable? initially i have y(x) and x, now wich variable is indipendet and wich is the dependent one? is it z(x) and y(z) ? thanks for your help :)

Comment: yes,and divide $dy$ everywehere.Where is the product?

Comment: @AserOsman,wait a minute i'll write full answer

Comment: @Battani Thank you very much, your explanation is very clear. But is it possibile to espress the solution in form of y=f(x) ( also without the integral) ?

Comment: You are welcome)I believe it is possible but unfortunately i don't know how

Comment: @AserOsman I'm pretty sure it's only expressible in terms of the error function $\erf$, but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Write th equation $\ds{y' - yy'x^{2} - x = 0}$ as
$\ds{-x\,\dd x + \pars{1 - x^{2}y}\dd y = 0}$. Multiply both members by
$\ds{\mathrm{C}\pars{x,y}}$. It means
$\ds{-\mathrm{C}\pars{x,y}x\,\dd x + \mathrm{C}\pars{x,y}\pars{1 - x^{2}y}\dd y
     = 0}$ and set
\begin{align}
\partiald{\bracks{-\mathrm{C}\pars{x,y}x}}{y} & =
\partiald{\bracks{\mathrm{C}\pars{x,y}\pars{1 - x^{2}y}}}{x}
\\[3mm]
\imp\quad-\,\partiald{\mathrm{C}\pars{x,y}}{y}\,x & =
\partiald{\mathrm{C}\pars{x,y}}{x}\pars{1 - x^{2}y}-2xy\,\mathrm{C}\pars{x,y}
\end{align}
It is convenient, by simplicity, to choose $C$ as a function of $y$ ( independent of $x$ ) such that $\mathrm{C}\pars{y} = \expo{y^{2}}$. It means that
$$
\dd\Phi = -x\expo{y^{2}}\,\dd x + \expo{y^{2}}\pars{1 - x^{2}y}\dd y = 0
\quad\mbox{is an exact differential.}
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
\partiald{\Phi}{x} & = -x\expo{y^{2}}\quad\imp\quad\Phi = -\,\half\,x^{2}\expo{y^{2}} + \mathrm{f}\pars{y}
\\[3mm]
\partiald{\Phi}{y} & = -x^{2}y\expo{y^{2}} + \mathrm{f}'\pars{y} = \expo{y^{2}}\pars{1 - x^{2}y}\quad\imp\quad\mathrm{f}'\pars{y} = \expo{y^{2}}\ \imp\
\mathrm{f}\pars{y} = \int\expo{y^{2}}\,\dd y
\end{align}

So, your solution is given implicitily by
$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\mbox{}\\
\ds{\quad\mbox{constant} = \Phi =
-\,\half\,x^{2}\expo{y^{2}} + \int\expo{y^{2}}\,\dd y\quad}
\\ \mbox{} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

An approach **if you are OK with a power series representation** is to pause at this step:

$$y'(1-yx^2) = x \\\text{or}\\ y'-x^2y'y=x$$

Now assume $$y = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_kx^k$$

Subtraction, differentiation w.r.t. $x$ and multiplication with $x^2$ behaves nicely on the coefficients in the space of linear combination of monomials. The tricky/confusing part will be the product $y'(1-yx^2)$. It will turn into a (shifted) self-convolution (with inverse sign) for our coefficients. The key here will be that right hand side is very simple. Only one 1-value ($1\cdot x$) and all other are 0.

For almost all positions there will be an equation one particular coefficient equals negative scalar product of two permuted coefficient vectors. Gosh this got more confusing then I thought. I think I will need to ask a question on my own for the resolution of this.

Comment: thanks for your answer unfortunatly i don't have any knowledge of power series :/